# JSON double encoding the value

Tags: json, mongodb, express, session

So I would like to store a session for the users in my Mongo db database. I am using express-session and connect-mongo npm packages.

```
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: db
  })
}));
```

I store it in the session

```
req.session.userId = IdOfUserFromDatabaseQuery;

{
    "_id" : "hcog9Z9Jjawb5joIax-z1Wv7txV--nYA",
    "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"summoner\":\"Blis\",\"summonerId\":\"5ba7ec0293b6220cc2f12959\"}",
    "expires" : ISODate("2018-10-07T20:39:41.911Z")
}
```

The session key: value is encoded like "{\"cookie\":... and I want it to be {cookie:...

I searched and found that this type of encoding means that it is double encoded. I have checked. I am not encoding it when I put it into the session, which means what is probably happening is express-session automatically JSON encodes, and also when I use...

```
store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: db
  })
}));
```

to connect the session to the mongo database, it is probably encoding it again. How do I stop it from being encoded when I store it in the database using the MongoStore function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. So the module connect-mongo has an option to json stringify the data before it gets sent.

```
    app.use(session({
  secret: 'work hard',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: db,
    stringify: false <---- This is set to true by default, which was causing my data to get double JSON encoded.
  })
}));
```